# Confluence Rest Update page from file

Tags: bash, curl, confluence

I can successfully create and update a Confluence wiki page with simple content. However I get an error when attempting to update with more than just a string.

I have a collection of documentation in git repository formatted in Markdown. Due to legacy needs, I use pandoc to convert these to word to deploy in a documentation system. We are moving to Confluence so I want to deploy updates as wiki pages.

I have page ID, Version, and the Title

```
echo "update page ${title} - ${pagid}/${pagver}"
content=$(pandoc -t HTML ${file})

json="{"
json+='"id":"'${pagid}'","title":"'${title}'","type":"page",'
json+='"space":{"key":"'${SPACE}'"},'
json+='"version":{"number":"'${pagver}'"},'
json+='"body":{"storage":{"value":"'${content}'","representation":"storage"}}'
json+="}"

${curlcmd} -n -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "${json}" ${apilb}/content/${pagid} 2>/dev/null
```

If I set content to `<p>this is test content</p>` it works fine. However complex html gets this error:

```
{"statusCode":500,"message":"org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@22ae1ec8; line: 1, column: 157]"}
```

Is there a better way to send the output of file to update a Confluence wiki page?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out `storePage` in the Confluence Command Line Interface (CLI):

https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CSOAP/Documentation#Documentation-runFromAttachmentList

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.confluence.cli/cloud/overview?src=sidebar

You should be able to get a free trail of this if you have not before.

Comment: I will give that a try. Was thinking the API would be more portable, but a working solution would be even better. :)